# Haskell: Couldn't match expected type ‘a1’ with actual type ‘a’

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
module Coleccion where
  data Pila a= Pil [a] deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
  data Cola a= Col [a] deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)

  class Coleccion n where
    esVacia::n->Bool
    insertar::n->a->n
    primero::n->a
    eliminar:: n->n
    size::n->Int;



  instance Coleccion (Pila a) where
    esVacia (Pil [])= True
    esVacia (Pil _ )= False
    primero (Pil x) = last x
    eliminar (Pil x)= (Pil (init x))
    size (Pil []) = 0
    size (Pil pila) = length pila;
```

And when I compile it with GHCI I have:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘a1’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration at Coleccion.hs:18:12-29
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          primero :: forall a1. Pila a -> a1
        at Coleccion.hs:21:5-11
    • In the expression: last x
      In an equation for ‘primero’: primero (Pil x) = last x
      In the instance declaration for ‘Coleccion (Pila a)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: [a] (bound at Coleccion.hs:21:18)
        primero :: Pila a -> a1 (bound at Coleccion.hs:21:5)
```

The functions that I have a problem with them are functions that have a type distinct from n or predefined types (Bool, Integer...) like, for example, primero. For example, esVacia, size & eliminar are working OK.
I don't know what is wrong in declarations or in instance code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your class declaration, the functions `insertar` and `primera` promise the consumer to work with *any* type `a` whatsoever (by the way: you're missing the `insertar` implementation). However, when implementing them in your class instance, you try to make it work with the specific `a`, which is the "contents" of `Pila`. The promise of the class is broken - the functions in the instance do not, in fact, work with *any* type `a`, - and so the compiler complains.

If you want to make this work, you need to declare class `Coleccion` in a way that says "*`n` is a collection, which contains elements of type `a`, and here are the functions that should work with those types `n` and `a`*".

**One way to do this** is to use an *associated type*:

```
class Coleccion n where
    type Elemento n
    esVacia::n->Bool
    insertar::n -> Elemento n -> n
    primero::n -> Elemento n
    eliminar:: n->n
    size::n->Int;
```

This declaration says: "*whoever defines an instance of `Coleccion` for some type `n`, should also provide a way to determine what the type of elements of that collection is, and `insertar` and `primero` should work on that very type, not on some random unrelated one*". You would implement it like this:

```
instance Coleccion (Pila a) where
    type Elemento (Pila a) = a
    ...
    primero (Pil x) = last x
```

Here, you say: "*my collection is `Pila a`, and its elements are `a`, and here's how `primero` should work on it*".

(NOTE: you'll need the `TypeFamilies` extension to do this)

**Alternatively**, you could use *functional dependencies* and two-parameter type class:

```
class Coleccion n el | n -> el where
    ...
    insertar::n -> el -> n
    primero::n -> el
```

This declaration says: "*whenever you define an instance of `Coleccion` for some type `n`, you should also specify what the element `el` of that collection is*". The "arrow" after the "pipe" says that the collection type should unambiguously determine what the element is - that is, you can't have one collection contain elements of several different types.

Then you implement it like this:

```
instance Coleccion (Pila a) a where
    ...
    primero (Pil x) = last x
```

(NOTE: you'll need `FunctionalDependencies` and `MultiParamTypeClasses` extensions for this)

Answer (score 2):

@Fyodor Soikin solution is great this one other way to do this

```
module Coleccion where
  data Pila a= Pil [a] deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
  data Cola a= Col [a] deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)

  class Coleccion n where
    esVacia::n->Bool
    --insertar::n->a->n
    primero::n->n
    eliminar:: n->n
    size::n->Int



  instance Coleccion (Pila a) where
    esVacia (Pil [])= True
    esVacia (Pil _ )= False
    primero (Pil xs) = (Pil [(last xs)])
    eliminar (Pil xs)= (Pil (init xs))
    size (Pil []) = 0
    size (Pil xs) = length xs
```

now using  Monad , Functor and Applicative you can do anything you want